# Is it possible to run only particular sub under debugger?

Tags: perl, debugging

I want to print stacktrace only of particular subroutine. 
Is it possible ? Script is running under perl without `-d` option.

Simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

foo();

sub foo {
    print "Hello world\n";
    # enable debugger from this moment with PERLDB_OPTS='NonStop frame=1'
    bar();
    # disable debugger from this moment
    return;
}

sub bar {
    print "Just another Perl hacker\n";
    return;
}
```

Expected output:

```
$ perl test.pl 
Hello world
    entering main::bar
Just another Perl hacker
```

I tried to play with `$ENV{PERL5DB}` but no effect:

```
$ENV{PERL5DB}='sub DB::DB {} sub sub {print ++$i, " $sub\n"; &$sub}';
bar();
$ENV{PERL5DB} = undef;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just set `$DB::frame` directly from within your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

foo();

sub foo {
    print "Hello world\n";
    $DB::frame = 1;
    bar();
    $DB::frame = 0;
    return;
}

sub bar {
    print "Just another Perl hacker\n";
    return;
}
```

This can be run as follows:

```
$ PERLDB_OPTS=NonStop perl -d try.pl
Hello world
   entering main::bar
Just another Perl hacker
```

That's it.

---

If you wanted to do it manually and define your own custom debugger, you could do it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

foo();

sub foo {
    print "Hello world\n";
    $DB::xtrace = 1;
    bar();
    $DB::xtrace = 0;
    return;
}

sub bar {
    print "Just another Perl hacker\n";
    return;
}
```

```
$ PERL5DB='BEGIN { package DB; sub DB {} sub sub { print STDERR "    entering $sub\n" if $xtrace; &$sub } }' perl -d try.pl
Hello world
    entering main::bar
Just another Perl hacker
```

Comment: Thanks, `$DB::frame` is exactly what I need :)

Comment: But... How to run debugger in runtime, without `-d` option at start ? I tried to use [Enbugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Enbugger/lib/Enbugger.pod) module, but I can not pass `PERLDB_OPTS='NonStop frame=1'` options to it.

Comment: @PaulSerikov Why don't you want to pass `-d` at start?

Answer (score 1):

Is this just a question about how to produce a stack trace? You don't need the debugger for that.

```
use Carp;
sub bar {
    Carp::cluck("entering main::bar");
    ...
}
```

Comment: no, it's not a question of stacktrace. I need to print name of each function immediately after it was executed. I can't use stacktrace since it may not reach moment of printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You would benefit from converting your script to a modulino.

The problem you are experiencing is that `foo()` is called directly as soon as Perl enters runtime. But this is not the behavior you desire from a debugging perspective.

The purpose of a modulino is to allow the bulk of the code to be treated as an embedded module, and to allow the startup or kickoff code to only run if the script is run directly, but to not be run if the script is instead loaded as a module. By doing this you're able to write a test suite against the modulino code, leaving only minimal kickoff code outside the reach of unit tests.

One of several writeups on this topic exists here: https://perlmaven.com/modulino-both-script-and-module

For your purposes, the modulino lets you be more selective about what you run with the Perl debugger.

If you structured your code as follows, you would be more successful:

```
package MyModulino;
use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(foo bar);

sub foo {
    print "Hello world\n";
    # enable debugger from this moment with PERLDB_OPTS='NonStop frame=1'
    bar();
    # disable debugger from this moment
    return;
}

sub bar {
    print "Just another Perl hacker\n";
    return;
}

package main;

if(!caller) {
    MyModulino->import();
    foo();
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
perl -I/some/path/to/script -e 'do "scriptname"; MyModulino::bar()'
```

In other words, you can now treat `scriptname`, whatever it is, as a module with a package named `MyModulino`, and you can call `bar()` directly rather than relying on `foo()` to call it. The call to `foo()` only happens if `caller()` returns false, which it will do if you run the program directly, but will not do if you invoke it as a module.

By treating `scriptname` as a module, the `foo()` call doesn't run implicitly, and your debugger code can invoke `bar()` from the `MyModulino` package.

This one liner should drop you into the debugger without having called `foo()`.

```
perl -d -I/path/to/script -e 'do "scriptname"; MyModulino::bar()'
```

You can combine this technique along with `Test::MockModule` to mock the portions of the call stack you don't care about when testing `bar()` also. But when you start going down that path you really should invest the time to implement these strategies in an automated test script. The 'modulino' advice still applies in that case.